# Invoke g++/clang from python to compile a python string

Tags: python, c++, compilation

I am currently writing an application that generates C++ code into a python string. I want to compile this code and create a `.so` from it.

The easiest way is to write the python string containing the code into a file, and use `subprocess.Popen(...)` to invoke g++/clang to compile it into a `.so`, but I would rather not write the string to disk first and have that as an intermediate step.

I have looked online for g++/clang bindings in python, and they were all simply parsers(for example, `libclang`), and do not actually compile anything.

Is there an alternative method that I'm missing here? Or do I need to bite the bullet and use `subprocess`?

Comment: You can pipe code to gcc (and probably clang) by using `-` as a filename, but you have to specify the language too if I remember correctly. (Something like `echo "c_code"|gcc -xc - -o whatever`.) Should be doable from python.

Comment: Ah, nice one. Feel free to add that as an answer. If anyone has any python-only way to do it I would prefer that, but I'm happy with this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mat's comment in python3 using the `input` argument of [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

This uses the fact that g++ accepts code from standard input when passed the file name `-`. Because there is no file name suffix, the compiler cannot guess the language, so it should be specified with [`-x`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html).

The `encoding` argument was added to make the input argument accept a string, otherwise it expects a bytes-like object.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import locale

def compile_cpp(cpp_code_as_string, exe_name):
    command = ('g++', '-xc++', '-', '-o', exe_name)
    subprocess.run(command, input=cpp_code_as_string, encoding=locale.getpreferredencoding())

hello = '''
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\\n";
  return 0;
}
'''

compile_cpp(hello, 'hello')
subprocess.run(['./hello'])
```

Comment: I did this, except with `g++` for `gcc`, and it works. The reason `gcc` does not work is because `g++` finds your standard library headers.

Comment: @OneRaynyDay: Yes, thank you, I missed the tag. Edited to C++.